# Firestore Error: Unable to create document inside a nested collection with REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore DB structure: `2020/abhishek/friend-requests/` where `2020` is a collection, `abhishek` is a document and `friend-requests` is a collection inside the document.

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm trying to create a new document inside `friend-requests` using REST API.

**What I did so far?**

I made a POST request to this endpoint:
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fuze-eee88/databases/(default)/documents/2020/abhishek/friend-requests/?documentId=newdocument

Request body:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "status": {
      "booleanValue":"true"
    }
  }
}
```

**The error I get:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Document parent name \"projects/fuze-eee88/databases/(default)/documents/2020//abhishek\" lacks a resource id at index 55.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are getting that error because the  document with the ID `newdocument`  already exists in your Firestore database.You have to choose a unique ID for every new document that you add to Firestore database. You may try using a different ID, such as `newdocument1`  instead of `new document`.

You can  have a look at below sample url

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME>/<YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID>/<YOUR_SUBCOLLECTION_NAME>/?documentId=<YOUR_UNIQUE_ID>
```

After editing the above url as per your configuration will become:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fuze-eee88/databases/(default)/documents/2020/abhishek/friend-requests/?documentId=newdocument1
```